# How to pass an object dynamically in the define function of Ext object in Sencha ExtJS 6.0.2?

Tags: class, extjs, typescript

Taking a look at the following segment of code you will see two cases where the sencha cmd return an error and one case that it doesn't

```
var memoryStore = new MemoryStore<Individual>("personnel", [
        'name', 'email', 'phone'
    ], [
        new Individual("Batman", "etsigoustaro@thefirm.com", "+306969696969"),
        new Individual("Jean Luc", "jeanluc.picard@enterprise.com", "555-111-1111"),
        new Individual("Worf", "worf.moghsson@enterprise.com", "+30 696 969 6969"),
        new Individual("Deanna", "mr.data@enterprise.com", "+30 6969696969"),
        new Individual("Data", "deanna.troi@enterprise.com", "+30-6969696969"),
    ])

    //memoryStore.toExtJS()

    Ext.define('extTestTs.store.Personnel', (function(){
        //return JSON.stringify(memoryStore.toExtJS())  //fails

        //return Ext.Object.merge({},{})    //fails

        return {} //succeeds
    })());
```

As you see we have removed everything, even `extends` is missing but as long as you are typing an object by hand it works. When this object is returned from a function it stops to work!

What does the sencha cmd does behind the scenes? Is it parsing the plain javascript as a text file?..
Because if it was javascript it would run without an issue.

This is the error from sencha cmd console output:

> [ERR] C2008: Requirement had no matching files (extTestTs.store.Personnel) -- /home/student/Desktop/Typescript/extTestTs/classic/src/view/main/List.js:8:10
>   [ERR] 
>   [ERR] BUILD FAILED
>   [ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any files for /home/student/Desktop/Typescript/extTestTs/classic/src/view/main/List.js::ClassRequire::extTestTs.store.Personnel
>   [ERR] 
>   [ERR] Total time: 3 seconds
>   [ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/student/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.1.2.15/plugins/ext/current/plugin.xml:425: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/student/Desktop/Typescript/extTestTs/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:380: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/student/Desktop/Typescript/extTestTs/.sencha/app/init-impl.xml:382: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any files for /home/student/Desktop/Typescript/extTestTs/classic/src/view/main/List.js::ClassRequire::extTestTs.store.Personnel

How could we overcome this restriction of explicitly defining the object and rather define it more dynamically?

*The goal is to make typescript work with ExtJS but not with the extreme unconventional solutions others propose, like forking typescript itself*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround

First allow unreachable code in typescript

Here is a screenshot from the IntelliJ settings:

[image: Screenshot from the IntelliJ settings]

And the code in the questions transforms into that

```
var memoryStore = new MemoryStore<Individual>("personnel", [
        'name', 'email', 'phone'
    ], [
        new Individual("Batman", "etsigoustaro@thefirm.com", "+306969696969"),
        new Individual("Jean Luc", "jeanluc.picard@enterprise.com", "555-111-1111"),
        new Individual("Worf", "worf.moghsson@enterprise.com", "+30 696 969 6969"),
        new Individual("Deanna", "mr.data@enterprise.com", "+30 6969696969"),
        new Individual("Data", "deanna.troi@enterprise.com", "+30-6969696969"),
    ])

    //memoryStore.toExtJS()

    Ext.define('extTestTs.store.Personnel', function (Personnel) {
        return memoryStore.toExtJS()

        return {} //do not erase this line
    });
```

Yeah the line `return {}` might seem totally redundant but (obviously) the sencha cmd is trying to parse the file before it includes it in the requires

Now sencha cmd gives a success and executing `sencha app web start` the sample app works ok